# Web page show nothing but white page only

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I design a web site when I open it in browser it show nothing but white page I can not understand why this is happening 
http://nethunters.org/nethunters-site-master/
please check this link and help me  advance thanks

Comment: Probably some unclosed script/stlye/header tag?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/?acceptlanguage=&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fnethunters.org%2Fnethunters-site-master%2F

Comment: can you highlight that tag please because I can not found it

Answer (score 3):

That happen because of the `opacity: 0;` rule you've in `animsition` class affected to your body tag.

If you remove the class from the `body` tag or you change the `opacity` value to `1` you will be able to see your design.

**NOTE :** As guys comments below says you should check the validity of you content, also check the browser console for the errors like :

> GET http://nethunters.org/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)

Hope this helps.

Comment: and a file is not properly loaded it seems : https://image.ibb.co/eDZJzv/error.png

Comment: This is correct, but it is worth noting that the w3c validator shows a number of errors with the html at that link. It is worth using it to check your html for validity. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fnethunters.org%2Fnethunters-site-master%2F

Answer (score 0):

Change css:

```
 opacity: 0; to 1
```

```
.animsition, .animsition-overlay {

  animation-fill-mode: both;

  opacity: 1;

  position: relative;

}
```